# MySQL Select Statement Not Returning List in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to return a list of email addresses that expire 30 days from now. To do that I need to look for users from 335 days ago since all accounts expire 365 days after setup and I only log the setup date in MySQL as a timestamp.  Here is the PHP statement I am using which is not returning a list for me.  Any ideas:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `TYPE` > 0 AND `ID` > 0 AND `UPDATED_DATE` = DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 335 DAY)";
$result = $conn->query($sql2);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "email: " . $row["EMAIL"]. $row["ID"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: did you mean `UPDATED_DATE >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 335 DAY)`?

Comment: first test your `mqsql` query without `php` and see result if there are result so the isseu with `php` code if there are not then the error with `mysql` query

Comment: It should be `<=` since you want accounts older than that date.

Comment: What is the datatype of `updated_date`? is it a `DATE` or `DATETIME`?

Comment: and please when you gonna ask question about `mysql` write the table struct the most simple way to run the code `show create table table_name` the result gonna be like `CREATE TABLE \`test\` (
 \`id\` int(30) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 \`name\` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`),
 UNIQUE KEY \`id\` (\`id\`),
 UNIQUE KEY \`id_2\` (\`id\`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1000001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` copy it to the question`

Comment: updated_date is a timestamp.  Also...I can't use <= or >= as I only want to return those that exactly exist at 30 days out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ignore the time part of the timestamp, so it should be:

```
WHERE DATE(updated_date) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 335 DAY))
```

Otherwise, you're only matching accounts that were created at the same exact time of day as you run the query.

Comment: Thanks.  I was not ignoring the time part of the timestamp and DATE( ) took care of it.